# Error: Angular CLI v10.1.0 and later (and no `tsconfig.base.json`)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, eslint, tslint

In my [Angular 11 project](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) I'm trying to [replace tslint with eslint](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-an-angular-cli-project-from-codelyzer-and-tslint) but the following command:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

gives me this error:

> Error: Angular CLI v10.1.0 and later (and no `tsconfig.base.json`) is required in order to run this schematic. Please update your workspace and try again.

how come my Angular CLI version is already higher than `10.1.0` but I still have the `tsconfig.base.json` file and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

I've solved the issue by running

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 9 --to 10
```

this will correctly remove the `tsconfig.base.json` file and allows me to proceed with the migration.

Comment: Epic solution. A project I was brought on to apparently had manually updated to v10, without using the update script as shown here, leaving the repo in a weird partially updated state. Running this script fixed it!

Comment: This not work for me: × Migration failed: Cannot read property 'Loose' of undefined

Comment: Didn't work for me in Angular 13. The command just exits after "found dependencies": https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24477

Answer (score 2):

In my case, interestingly, the Angular is already updated to version 10, but `tsconfig.base.json` still exists in the folder, so I deleted the file manually and re-run again `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`. This solution works .